# Opened viewport now project has no colour

Tags: 3d-view

I opened a viewport and couldn't close it again so I closed my project. I've loaded it up again and my project has no colour. Can anyone help? Am I still in a viewport? How do I close it because it's the whole screen.

Comment: Hello :). Could you please add a screenshot?

Comment: No color...? In preview, in render, in Cycles, in Eevee? Is it possible that you opened the project from 2.79?